# Undefined Name "Y", as well as weird outputting issue

Tags: java, file, loops, undefined

my code compiles, but when I try to run it, it gives me an error of "undefined name" when I'm running a Y/N loop control variable.  I've input the coding of the whole program below.

Also, it displays the closing dialog while it's asking the loop question.. what did I do wrong here?

```
//declarations
String itemName;  //name of item
String itemPriceInput;  //user input of price
double itemPrice;  //parsed name of price
String itemQuantityInput;  //user input of quantity
double itemQuantity; //parsed input of quantity
String inputMore; //loop control

//Create file instance
java.io.File itemAttributes = new java.io.File("Items_In_Stock.txt");

//Create a scanner for the file
Scanner input = new Scanner(itemAttributes);

System.out.println("Welcome to the inventory list program");  //welcome dialog for user
System.out.println("This program will show items on hand, as well as their info"); //more dialog

System.out.println("Enter 'Y' to proceed, or 'Q' to quit"); //asking to start program

inputMore=input.next(); //taking input for loop control

while (inputMore.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) //beginning outer loop

{
  while (input.hasNext()) //beginning inner loop
  {
    itemName=input.next(); // input item name
    System.out.print (" ");

    itemPriceInput=input.next(); //input item price
    itemPrice=Double.parseDouble(itemPriceInput); //parse to double
    System.out.print (" ");

    itemQuantityInput=input.next(); //input quantity
    itemQuantity=Double.parseDouble(itemQuantityInput); //parse to double

    System.out.println("Name: " + itemName + " " + "Price: " + itemPrice + " " + "Quantity: " + itemQuantity); //display input items
  } //close inner loop

  System.out.print("Enter 'Y' to input more, or 'Q' to quit"); //asking user to input more, or quit

} //close outer loop
  input.close(); //close program

  System.out.println("Thank you for using the program.  Goodbye");//goodbye statement
```

Comment: Can you show us the full error message (with stack trace, if there is one) and indicate which line it's on?

Comment: You're using the same scanner for scanning the file and asking for user input (y/q). If you want to take user input from command line use another scanner `new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: No stack trace, because it compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your `txt` file contains data like

```
ddda 8998 787
gdfgd 8998 787
```

I can see two flaws so far:
As you are asking user `"Enter 'Y' to proceed, or 'Q' to quit"` you should take different scanner for this using `System.in`.

Also why are you using while loop inside?? You shoul use `if` condition there to be able to ask user for choice..

Here's the updated code. It will solve your issue:

```
// declarations
        String itemName; // name of item
        String itemPriceInput; // user input of price
        double itemPrice; // parsed name of price
        String itemQuantityInput; // user input of quantity
        double itemQuantity; // parsed input of quantity
        String inputMore; // loop control

        // Create file instance
        java.io.File itemAttributes = new java.io.File("Items_In_Stock.txt");

        // Create a scanner for the file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(itemAttributes);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the inventory list program");
        System.out
                .println("This program will show items on hand, as well as their info");

        System.out.println("Enter 'Y' to proceed, or 'Q' to quit");
//      inputMore = input.next(); // taking input for loop control

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//      System.out.println(inputMore);
        while (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")) // beginning outer loop

        {
            if(input.hasNext()) // beginning inner loop
            {
                itemName = input.next(); // input item name

                itemPriceInput = input.next(); // input item price
                itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(itemPriceInput); // parse to
                                                                // double

                itemQuantityInput = input.next(); // input quantity
                itemQuantity = Double.parseDouble(itemQuantityInput); // parse
                                                                        // to
                                                                        // double

                System.out.println("Name: " + itemName + " " + "Price: "
                        + itemPrice + " " + "Quantity: " + itemQuantity); // display
                                                                            // input
                                                                            // items
            } // close inner loop
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No more records");
                break;
            }

            System.out.print("Enter 'Y' to input more, or 'Q' to quit"); // asking
                                                                            // user
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // input
                                                                            // more,
                                                                            // or
//          inputMore = input.next();                                                               // quit

        } // close outer loop
        input.close(); // close program

        System.out.println("Thank you for using the program.  Goodbye");// goodbye
                                                                        // statement}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake I see is

```
while (inputMore.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

You forgot to update inputMore at the end of the loop, in other words `inputMoreinputMore.equalsIgnoreCase("y")` will always return true because you never change it's value.

you can either change to

```
if (inputMore.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

or add at the end of the loop an other

```
inputMore = input.hext();
```

Comment: Complete dumb newbie quesiton... I usually use a gui input, as opposed to scanner, but the assignment requires scanner.  What do you mean by updating the inputMore variable at the end of the loop?

Comment: @JeffHall sorry my answer was lacking, I've updated it